# Need Help In Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My script code like :

```
function changePrice(id) {
    var url = '<?php echo $base_url ?>home/getprice/';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: 'id='+id,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg); 
            /* 
            "regular_price": "800",
            "discount_price": 720
            */
        }
    });
}
```

I want to both regular price and discount price on separate variable.How??

Comment: what is in msg? console.log(msg), then check the console.

Comment: Do `msg.regular_price` and `msg.discount_price` not work for you?

Comment: yeah if msg is an object i'm agree with @Swaraj Giri

Comment: success:function(msg)
{
 var price = msg.regular_price;
 alert(price);
}  /* undifened */

Comment: @ZuberMafat `var obj = JSON.parse('{' + msg + '}');
var regular  = data.regular_price;
var discount = data.discount_price;`

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the response as `"regular_price": "800", "discount_price": 720` then make it valid JSON, parse it and get the properties.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{' + msg + '}');
//     valid json    -^-----------^-

// get object properties
var regular  = data.regular_price;
var discount = data.discount_price;
```

---

**UPDATE :** If response data is valid JSON format then set [`dataType: 'json'`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax1) option.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: 'id='+id,
    // set response datatype as json
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        // get properties
        var regular  = msg.regular_price;
        var discount = msg.discount_price;
    }
});
```

---

Or parse it directly if the response is a string.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: 'id='+id,
    success: function(msg) {
        // parse the string
        var data = JSON.parse(msg);
        // get properties
        var regular  = data.regular_price;
        var discount = data.discount_price;
    }
});
```

Comment: o/p : 
 {
  "regular_price": "50",
  "discount_price": 45
 }    
success:function(msg)
{
 var obj = JSON.parse('{' + msg + '}');
 var regular  = data.regular_price;
 var discount = data.discount_price;
 alert(regular);
} 
// SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In server side ajax call:

```
$respose['regular_price'] = 120;
$respose['discount_price'] = 100;
echo json_encode($response);
```

In JS: Considering msg is an json object

```
var data = JSON.parse(msg);
var regular  = data.regular_price;
var discount = data.discount_price;
```

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: success:function(msg)
    {
     var newdata = JSON.parse(msg);
     var regular  = newdata.regular_price;
     var discount = newdata.discount_price;
     alert(regular);
      
    }

Comment: Means the return type of message is not an json object

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to all..Here are the solution :

```
     <script>
      function changePrice(id)
       {
            var url = '<?php echo $base_url ?>home/getprice/';
            $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'post',
            data:'id='+id,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(msg)
            {
                var regular  = msg.regular_price;
                var discount = msg.discount_price;
            } 
        });
     }
  </script>
```

My Function :

```
  $new = array (
     "regular_price" => $result->price,
      "discount_price" => $price
    );
    $newarray = json_encode($new, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    print_r($newarray);
```